# Converting an image into an array vs Directly initializing an array the size of the image

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

Using google colab, I want to create a `numpy` array, `Y`, of similar shape to an image I have (further explained below) - `9999 x 146,666`.

I found that there are two ways I can go by this:

#### Method 1

Load the image using:

```
from PIL import Image

Z = np.asarray(Image.open(*ImagePath*))
```

to transform the image into an array (I'm not sure how this takes place though).

Then I can simply say `Y = Z`. When I look closely to the amount of memory `Y` eats up using `sys.getsizeof(Y)` it reports back only **112** bytes!!

#### Method 2

Is if I crudely initialize a `numpy.array` of zeros of shape `9999 x 146,666` using:

```
Y = np.array(np.zeros((9999,146666)))
```

to which it non-surprisingly crashes my colab instance (which I assume means it ate up all of the memory colab had to offer)!

---

So my question is, ***what is the difference between the two arrays such that one weighed in about 112 bytes and the other blew my PC up***?

---

### P.S Yes, I checked the size AND type of the array `Y` in both methods. They are the same.

EDIT: I was informed that it might have something to do with how PIL works as a library. I.E it creates a pointer to the file on disk and only loads it when an operation is performed on it. But it still remains, why does the array not blow my session up like the initialization does?

Comment: Try you check a number of items of `arr2` and size of item of `arr2` in bytes. Like: `np.array(np.zeros((99,146))).size` and `np.array(np.zeros((99,146))).itemsize`. You'll see it's enormously large.

Comment: What is the size of `Z`?

Comment: The size of ```z``` is 9999x146666

Comment: Yea but im trying to understand the working behind this difference in size here

Comment: If `Z.shape` is `(9999x146666)`; AND `Y=Z` then `Y` will have the same shape; and presumably `Z` would have blown up your computer. Please provide a [mre].